# extern global device variable previously defined in cuda c++

Tags: c++, cuda, global-variables, header-files

I have three files: a.cu, b.cu, and c.h. I want to have debug variables accessible to all compilation units, so I declared them as extern in c.h, and defined only in a.cu, per the answer here [Global Variable within Multiple Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627941/global-variable-within-multiple-files):

> a.cu

```
#include "c.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

bool h_debug;                                                                       //works fine
//__device__ bool d_debug;                     //POINT A

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    h_debug = (argc > 1 ? true : false);
    std::cout<<"Host: "<<(h_debug ? "true" : "false")<<std::endl;
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_debug, &h_debug, sizeof(bool));  
    std::cout<<cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError())<<std::endl; 
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

> b.cu

```
#include "c.h"
#include "stdio.h"

__global__ 
void myKernel(){
    if(d_debug){
        printf("device debug on\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("device debug off\n");
    }
}
```

> c.h

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

extern __device__ bool d_debug;
extern bool h_debug;

#endif  /* MAIN_H */
```

At the line marked POINT A, if I have it commented, the code compiles but I get a cuda error when running, as one might expect:

```
$ nvcc a.cu b.cu -o globalTest
$ globalTest
Host: true
invalid device symbol
```

If I un-comment the line to define the d_debug, I get a compiler error that doesn't make sense to me ...

```
$ nvcc a.cu b.cu -o globalTest
a.cu:1:32: warning: unknown option after ‘#pragma GCC diagnostic’ kind [-Wpragmas]
a.cu:6:13: error: redefinition of ‘bool d_debug’
c.h:4:13: error: ‘bool d_debug’ previously declared here
```

Why is it not working like the global host variable? How should I create a global device variable which is accessible by all compilation units?

Comment: you'll need to incorporate device linking into your compilation sequence.  Otherwise a.cu and b.cu have *separate* copies of the `d_debug` device variable.  There are many questions here on the `cuda` tag that discuss this.

Comment: Thanks. Knowing what question to ask helps a lot :)

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24617318/cuda-constant-memory-value-not-correct) and linked duplicates generally covers the same ground.  `__device__` variables have the same kind of default *compilation-unit scope* as `__constant__` variables, and the solution approach is the same.

Comment: That answers it perfectly. It's not really a duplicate question but it is a duplicate answer ... should I close the question?

Comment: Your answer is fine IMO.  If someone wants to mark this a duplicate they can.  In the meantime, you can come back at some point and accept your answer.  I have upvoted it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

From comments by Robert Crovella and the answer here: [CUDA constant memory value not correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24617318/cuda-constant-memory-value-not-correct), The problem is that a.cu and b.cu have separate copies of d_debug. To prevent this, separate compilation and linking must be used; to that end, create relocatable device code (rather than executable device code).

> --relocatable-device-code {true|false}
>   -rdc     Enable (disable) the generation of relocatable device code. If disabled, executable device
>   code is generated. Relocatable device code must be linked before it
>   can be executed.
>
> Allowed values for this option: true, false.
>
> Default value: false

Changing nvcc arguments to:

```
nvcc -rdc=true a.cu b.cu -o globalTest
```

Resolves the issue.